# Can someone help me to get 2 specific time bar ohlc on 3 minute chart, previous day 3.57pm and today 9.39am. And the HiLo within this 2 bar together

Tags: pine-script

//Study Pivot
Study(title=“New Pivot”)

```
BarH1 = 0.0
BarL1 = 0.0
BarC1 = 0.0

if(hour(time) ==09 and minute(time) == 39)
BarH1 = high
BarL1 = low
BarC1 = close

BarH2 = 0.0
BarL2 = 0.0
BarC2 = 0.0

if(hour(time) ==15 and minute(time) == 57)
BarH2 = high
BarL2 = low
```

BarH3 = any function to compare barh1 and barh2 to get the highest hi

BarL3 = any function to compare barl1 and barl2 to get the lowest low

```
XHi = security(tickerId,BarH3)
XLo = security(tickerId,BarL3)
XCl = security(tickerId,BarC1)


PP = (XHi+XLo+XCl) / 3

Plot(PP,color=white,title=“Pivot”,style=line,line width=width)
```

I am very new to script and try to learn, hope to get help here. thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your market closes at 4pm and opens at 9:30am and you want to use the third 3min candle's values? If you want the fourth candle's values, change the 36 back to 39. I've marked the candles with `plotshape()` so you can manually confirm the calculation.

```
var float BarH1 = na
var float BarL1 = na
var float BarC1 = na
var float BarH2 = na
var float BarL2 = na
var float BarC2 = na
var float BarH3 = na
var float BarL3 = na
var float PP = na

openingBar = hour(time) == 09 and minute(time) == 36 and barstate.isconfirmed
closingBar = hour(time) == 15 and minute(time) == 57 and barstate.isconfirmed

if openingBar
    BarH1 := high
    BarL1 := low
    BarC1 := close
    BarH3 := max(BarH1, BarH2)
    BarL3 := min(BarL1, BarL2)
    PP := (BarC1 + BarH3 + BarL3) / 3
    
if closingBar
    BarH2 := high
    BarL2 := low

plot(PP)

plotshape(openingBar, location = location.belowbar, style = shape.triangleup, color = color.yellow, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(closingBar, location = location.abovebar, style = shape.triangledown, color = color.blue, size = size.tiny)
```